# Protecting public assets

Tags: assets, users, permissions

I'd like to manage access to assets with public URLs.

Is there a way to set permissions for anonymous users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is a bit self-serving, but I'm the author of the [Digital Download](https://plugins.craftcms.com/digital-download) plugin. It allows you to control how and when assets are downloaded.

You can [restrict](https://www.doublesecretagency.com/plugins/digital-download/docs/creating-a-token) downloads by a time period, maximum number of downloads, or tie them to a logged-in user.

[image: createToken]